# Oracle sql data represent problem (showing 1.12455E+10 format)

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm facing some problems while inserting and query data from the oracle SQL table. my table name is Table_Name
and it has two column names (id number, password varchar2). I make the inserting operation finely but when I query data then it as "1.14662E+10" this format.
so whats the problem is?

[image: here the screenshot of sqlplus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL*Plus, You can set the format of the column to display the content of the column. For your case, You need something like this:

```
column your_column_name format 9999999999
```

The number of 9s in the above command should be the number of digits in your column's max value.

See below example(`ROWNM` column):

```
SQL> select * from T;

     ROWNM NAME            TOTAL COLUMN1
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
1.2346E+17 Tejash     ########## test

SQL> column rownm format 999999999999999999
SQL>
SQL> select * from T;

              ROWNM NAME            TOTAL COLUMN1
------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
 123456789123456789 Tejash     ########## test

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is correctly stored and it's only a question of the way the client program (here SQL*Plus) is displaying the data.

As already answered you can use SQL*Plus formatting commands or use TO_CHAR function:

```
SQL> select x from t;

     X
----------
     1
1234567890
1.2346E+19

SQL> select to_char(x) from t;

TO_CHAR(X)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1
1234567890
12345678901234567890

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more trick for SQL*Plus (and SQLcl and SQL Developer) if you have several large number columns and don't want to set them all with `column`. There is a default display width for numbers, and beyond that size the formatting changes to scientific notation; but you can change that:

```
SQL> show numwidth
numwidth 10
SQL> select 12345, 123456789123456789 from dual;

     12345 123456789123456789
---------- ------------------
     12345         1.2346E+17

SQL> set numwidth 20
SQL> select 12345, 123456789123456789 from dual;

               12345   123456789123456789
-------------------- --------------------
               12345   123456789123456789

SQL>
```

It affects all number columns, even for smaller numbers, as you can see - so it's a broader approach and less targeted than individual `column` settings, but that can be useful sometimes.

You could also use `set numformat` to do more involved formatting, like adding group separators. [Read more about `set` options in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SET-system-variable-summary.html#GUID-BEC116D1-AEF3-499F-BDAB-4EAC4A149655).